# Can't Extrude Multiple Faces

Tags: extrude

I'm trying to extrude multiple faces of a cube at the same time but it seems to be locked to the z-axis. I'm relatively new to Blender and I've spent all evening trying to figure this out - it's driving me nuts. Even more annoying is I'm sure I've done this before with no problem, but now whenever I try to extend multiple faces it's locked to the z-axis. I even reset the factory defaults and it's still doing it. Please can someone tell me what have I overlooked?

[image]

Comment: Alt-E .. > Individual Faces?

Comment: Shift Spacebar > 0 ? @RobinBetts

Answer (score 3):

*Extrude* tool is set to *Region* by default. Just set it to *Extrude Individual*:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I think I perhaps didn't explain myself very well - I already tried this but couldn't get it to work - no matter what I did the extrude was being constrained to the z-axis. I've just figured it out. I was pressing the E key after selecting Extrude Individual - instead of just clicking and dragging